# switch statement with sentinel loop

Tags: java

I am having some trouble getting my sum function to work. I am trying to create a program that asks for a product number and a quantity using switch structure and a sentinel loop. It will run until 0 is entered. It should calculate the total number of products entered and the total value of all products entered. The quantity works just fine. It's the total value that will only work for the 1st product entered. I cannot get the sum for total to keep adding until 0 is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Mailorder {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //declare variables

    double product1 = 3.75;
    double product2 = 5.95;
    double product3 = 8.75;
    double product4 = 6.92;
    double product5 = 8.75;
    double product6 = 7.87;
    double total = 0.00;

    //read in product # 
    System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
        int product = input.nextInt();

    //read in quantity sold
    System.out.print("Enter quantity sold for 1 day: ");
        int quantity = input.nextInt();

    //switch case
    switch (product) 
      {
        case 1: total = product1 * quantity; break;
        case 2: total = product2 * quantity; break;
        case 3: total = product3 * quantity; break;
        case 4: total = product4 * quantity; break;
        case 5: total = product5 * quantity; break;
        case 6: total = product6 * quantity; break;
      default: System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid product number");
      }

    //keep reading data until the input is 0
    int sum1 = 0;
            while (quantity != 0) {
                     sum1 += quantity;

    int sum2 = 0;
            while (total != 0) {
                    sum2 +=total;
        }
     //read the next data
            System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
                    product = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter quantity sold for 1 day: ");
                    quantity = input.nextInt();
    }

    //print results
    System.out.println("The total number of products sold last week " + sum1);
    System.out.println("The total retail value of all products sold last week " + sum2);

}
}
```

Comment: If you use an array instead of six different variables you would not need the switch.

Comment: Thank you but I have to use the switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple scoping issues here.

First, you have placed your switch statement outside of your loop.  You should place it inside your loop.

Second, there is a scoping problem with `sum2`.  It is declared inside your sentinel loop, but referenced outside.  I'm not sure why you have a nested loop adding to `sum2`.  Here is the code with these issues resolved:

```
    public class Mailorder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create a scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declare variables

        double product1 = 3.75;
        double product2 = 5.95;
        double product3 = 8.75;
        double product4 = 6.92;
        double product5 = 8.75;
        double product6 = 7.87;

        //read in product #
        System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
        int product = input.nextInt();

        //read in quantity sold
        System.out.print("Enter quantity sold for 1 day: ");
        int quantity = input.nextInt();


        //keep reading data until the input is 0
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        while (quantity != 0) {
            sum1 += quantity;

            double total = 0.00;
            //switch case
            switch (product)
            {
                case 1: total += product1 * quantity; break;
                case 2: total += product2 * quantity; break;
                case 3: total += product3 * quantity; break;
                case 4: total += product4 * quantity; break;
                case 5: total += product5 * quantity; break;
                case 6: total += product6 * quantity; break;
                default: System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid product number");
            }
            sum2 += total;

            //read the next data
            System.out.print("Enter a product number: ");
            product = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter quantity sold for 1 day: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
        }


        //print results
        System.out.println("The total number of products sold last week " + sum1);
        System.out.println("The total retail value of all products sold last week " + sum2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's closer to what I have been trying to achieve but my total retail value is off

Comment: what do you mean by "off"? Remember, most real values cannot be exactly represented on a computer. When working with variables representing money, you should work in ints representing cents, not doubles representing dollars.

Comment: I got it to work I had to change the int for sum2 to double sum2 =0. It works for me now. I tried putting those loops in so many places. My brain just wouldn't see it. I see what I did wrong now and can't thank you enough for your help. That was a sad brutal 12 hours looking at that. I will hang my head in shame now. I'm going to play with it like you suggested with the ints representing cents. Oh and I'm sorry I didn't mean you were off, you were dead on. Again thank you for your help!!!